# how to make Rsync executable write files from android application?

Tags: java, android, linux, shell, rsync

I have a bash script which runs rsync, i can login to the android shell and can run files easily from the shell and it works fine and good. 
But when i run that bash script through the application, it runs but rsync throws and error at me that 0 bytes transferred and just creates a folder but doesn't sync the files to that folder.

Contents of bash file

```
./rsyncpie -Pav -e './sshpie -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i dbkey' ankit@ankitarora.co.in:~/rsyncdemo/* ../rsyncdemo/
```

Command i am using to call the file

```
 process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./run.sh",null,new File(basePath));
```

run.sh is that name of the file. I am making it as an executable correctly because i can go in the shell and execute and it just works fine, it just have problems when i do it from the application. 
Also i've added the permissions for reading and writing files in the application itself, but somehow it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Got this error in the logs in errorStream of process

```
output rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```